# About succinct data structure for dynamic key set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Now I am looking for any implementation or research works for succinct data structure for dynamic key set. In specifically, I am trying to implement the compression algorithm for radix trie that contains character strings as keys. In order to ease update, I use the balanced parenthesis encoding scheme proposed by Jacobson to represent the trie structure. Further, I implement the bitvector data structure with supporting rank(), select(), and access() operations. With these primitive operations, I implement the balanced_parenthesis bitvector operations such as findopen() and findclose() which is the primitive operations of trie traversal such as child(), sibling(), etc.

But the problem I encounter is when the trie is updated.

Is there any implementation or research of bitvector data structure for dynamic set with the primitive operations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably this paper (pdf) will help: ["Representing Dynamic Binary Trees Succinctly" by J. Ian Munro, Venkatesh Raman, Adam J. Storm](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/aladdin/wwwlocal/compression/p529-munro.pdf)?

Comment: Or one of these: ["Succinct Dynamic Dictionaries and Trees" by Raman & Rao](http://www.itu.dk/people/ssrao/icalp03-b.ps), ["A Uniform Approach Towards Succinct Representation of Trees" by Farzan & Munro](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.329.4437&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Is there any available code related to this?

Comment: I don't know any libraries implementing dynamic succinct trees. There is [libcds](https://github.com/fclaude/libcds), but it implements only simple static structures. They plan to add support for succinct trees, but most likely that would be static trees.

Comment: What about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array ? I'm not certain I understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: The links to the first two papers cited by @EvgenyKluev are dead. But they can be found on researchgate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220780531_Representing_dynamic_binary_trees_succinctly, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/27247708_Succinct_Dynamic_Dictionaries_and_Trees